# Problems with window.open in an hta?

Tags: javascript, window.open, hta, window.opener

Today, something that was previously working suddenly stopped working. It had been working fine for months, and all of the sudden it just broke. I reverted back to previous code, in case I had accidentally broken something myself, but even previous code that I know worked fine before breaks in the same way.

Our application currently runs as an hta, and until now, I had been able to open windows using window.open just fine. Now, however, window.open doesn't seem to work correctly, as the window that is opened does not have the specified dimensions. In the window, window.opener is null/not an object, but I think the source of this is probably the window.open, given how the window doesn't even open properly.

As an interesting note, if I just open the application in IE, instead of with the .hta file, it works perfectly. Is there any reason why this would suddenly break in the hta? Also, is there a workaround or someway to fix this problem?

Comment: Was IE updated by any chance?

Comment: I am also having difficulty with window.open. Seems that it gets 'lost' in the anonymous code, sometimes spinning until a timeout is reached. I'm not sure if these are related, but I'm going to flag yours as a favorite to see if anything you get might work with what I have... Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

window.open is not trusted under HTA rules, so window.showModelessDialog or window.showModalDialog should be used instead.

Check this [link](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2007/11/26/why-you-shouldnt-use-window.open-in-HTA.aspx). This might help.